# strange 404 error CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I have a wordpress site running. Firebug gives me the following error:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://mywebsite.de/var/www/vhosts/myserver.12345.de/httpdocs/pn/wp-content/themes/mytheme/wishlist.css?ver=2.0.15"
```

If i rename my wishlist.css then the error shows:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://mywebsite.de/wp-content/themes/mytheme/wishlist.css"
```

So basically, only when the wishlist.css file is present I get that 404 error. Anyone knows the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

The same 404 (Not Found) error was produced for both conditions. After renaming the CSS file, that became the first file not found - hence the second error.

Comment: Why is there this DOCUMENT_ROOT path? which of course leads to a 404 - because with this constellation the file is not accessible.The other linked file I have stated in my template file.

Comment: Are you referring to the DOCUMENT_ROOT used by the first or second error? The second looks more normal. i suggest that you check the security access of the folders being used to ensure that this is not causing the 404 errors.

Comment: Sorry I found it. Was very well hidden in some file with a very cryptical call.